# Get MotionEvent object using Application only

Tags: java, android, touch-event, intercept, motionevent

I'm developing a library for Android, that you can integrate in your project and using it passing only an instance of an `Application` of your project.
So, the question is:
Is there any way to get `MotionEvent` object (to get X and Y of users touch) using only an `Application` instance?

NOTE: Library should work with an API level older than 8, so using Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks is not possible.

Any help would be great! :)

Comment: So, you need to get MotioEvent from a View in your library?

Comment: No, but from a View some other project my library attach with...